# Brace-initialized vector constructor argument raises ambiguity error in gcc, but not in clang, and depends on size of vector

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, clang++

I have a C++ class that accepts a std::vector of std::pair<std::string, std::string> as its argument.  I'm finding that when I call the constructor with a braced-initializer list, I get an ambiguous constructor error from gcc, but only if the vector contains only one element.  The error does not occur if the vector contains two elements.  Also, clang can compile the program even if the vector contains only one element!  I tried versions of gcc from 5.x through 10.x, and clang from 10.x to 12.x.  My minimal reproducing case looks like this (compiled with `g++ -lstdc++ -std=c++14`):

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Foo {
 public:
  explicit Foo(const std::vector< std::pair<std::string, std::string> >& list) {
      (void)list;
  }

  Foo(const Foo& other)
  {
      (void)other;
  }
};

int main() {
    Foo f = Foo({{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}); // Compiles with clang and gcc.
    Foo g = Foo({{"a", "b"}}); // Compiles with clang, but not gcc.
    (void)f;
    (void)g;
}
```

Clang compiles this without an error, but with gcc-10.3 (for example), I get:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:19:29: error: call of overloaded 'Foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
   19 |     Foo g = Foo({{"a", "b"}}); // Compiles with clang, but not gcc.
      |                             ^
<source>:11:3: note: candidate: 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&)'
   11 |   Foo(const Foo& other)
      |   ^~~
<source>:7:12: note: candidate: 'Foo::Foo(const std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&)'
    7 |   explicit Foo(const std::vector< std::pair<std::string, std::string> >& list) {
      |            ^~~
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work in gcc?  I would have thought that the `explicit` keyword would be enough to disambiguate, and it really odd that it works when the vector has more that one element.  Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Update: the gcc error with length-1 list goes away if I replace the outer parens with brackets: ```Foo g = Foo{{{"a", "b"}}};```.  I'd still like to know why, though!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(const std::string& str)
    {
        std::cout << str;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f({ "a", "b", });
}
```

MSVC and gcc will compile it without any warnings or errors but the program crashes when you try to run it.

Let us try to figure out what is going on.

`std::string` has many constructors, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

One of them allows us do nifty things like the following:

```
std::string a("hello");
std::string b(a.begin(), a.end());
```

The same constructor can, unfortunately, be misused to create a mess like the following:

```
std::string c("a", "b");
```

The problem with your code is that the compiler does not know how to interpret the initialization list.

When you only have `{"a", "b"}` it can either be the constructor for a `std::string` or a pair of values.

The best you can do is to try not to confuse the compiler and rather use `std::make_pair` or use the correct brackets:

```
Foo f = Foo({std::make_pair("a", "b"), std::make_pair("c", "d")});
Foo g = Foo({std::make_pair("a", "b")});
```

Comment: shouldn't my use of ```explicit``` prevent this? I'm passing in a std::pair, so I'd think that ```explicit``` would make std::make_pair redundant, no?

Comment: The problem is not your constructor, but the compiler failing to deduce if it is a `std::string` or a `std::pair<std::string,std::string>`

Comment: @DavidLobron doesn't have a std::string constructor though. With std::string, that is because its constructor uses templates.

Comment: @CaptainHatteras, the strange thing is that it works if we use it in a function like [this](https://tio.run/##fY9NisMwDIX3PoVwobSQ6QFSk@WcYjaunRSBa4VYLgzBZ8/4p7RZjVbvPT9/SGaev@7GbNsBvXHRjqCQAi@jfgzik0VGh/y7j56jYVr2Sf6G/j4IYZwOAb6JYBVzvDk0vYA8T0IL6JFPhnxgCGz7vnFUM7PGRVXVYB3szADDERwGPmcuvGaiBV44HZmOUBDQt967VaaSDEUGpWrrMuESqpMdyHcaxoyzNf7x8loZSaSrEOgZHhr9qSxQ83LjRNRKWVzqdSusUhfmTaYua1O0lQnS@Z9mfU3b9gc). It is as if gcc ignores the fact that the constructor was marked as `explicit`. I tried to look at gcc's source code but only managed to get a headache.

Comment: @CaptainHatteras, I think the bottom line is that there is some sort of ambiguity in the initializers and we should make life easier for the compiler :-)

Comment: Your function init only has one overload, so it must be the correct one.

Comment: @CaptainHatteras It looks like gcc is still confused with Foo's constructor even if you use explicit and mark the copy constructor as deleted: [TIO](https://tio.run/##VZDBasQgEIbvPsXgQkggW2iPSZpjn6IXV80y4GqIY2kJPnuqZrubzsV//vn9HJTzfL5KuW0ntNIEpWFA52nR4jaypxcIDdLP0frSktxydNI1tNeRMWmE9/DhHKxsDheDsmOQSn/PSSPlUS2d9QSeVNftqGFvZoHLUNTOa@HQjDBWYNBTk9Bwr8ktcMeJQK6CjIBuzz1SuQpJukAwDCX1MuHiS8db4A/X64RTxf60vC@MyMrxXD2pqnlX2mjSPYs9Y2gJbgJt/bdd/oLJudd6hZWL/MSFxzZpmbXiEWLTH5Nv/5JlGrftFw)

Comment: @upkajdt True! Will investigate...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my *attempt* at explanation:

This line:

```
Foo f = Foo({{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}});
```

is roughly equivalent to the following:

```
Foo f = 
    Foo(
        std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<const char*>>{
            std::initializer<const char*>{"a", "b"},
            std::initializer<const char*>{"c", "d"}
        }
    );
```

Since `std::pair` has a constructor for any types `U1` and `U2`, `std::pair` can be constructed from an `initializer_list<const char*>`, or two `const char*`. The compiler most likely constructs two `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`, as it sees that we have an overload for a `std::vector` of the aforementioned type:

```
Foo f = 
    Foo(
        std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>{
            std::pair<std::string, std::string>("a", "b"),
            std::pair<std::string, std::string>("c", "d")
        }
    );
```

Since `std::vector<T>` has a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list<T>`, then the correct overload is chosen.

Let's take a look at this:

```
Foo g = Foo({{"a", "b"}});
```

which turns into:

```
Foo f = 
    Foo(
        std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<const char*>>{
            std::initializer_list<const char*>{"a", "b"}
        }
    );
```

Here it is not so obvious what we are doing. The compiler (assuming that we are just idiots) thinks that we *might* be trying to create a `Foo` from either an `initializer_list<const char*>` and then copying that `Foo`, or that we are directly creating the `Foo` with an `initilizer_list<initializer_list<const char*>>`. Since the constructor for `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>` takes a `std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>` and not a `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<const char*>>`, it is not clear to a dumb compiler what we are trying to do.

This is wild! However, consider what would happen here if the foo copy constructor was marked as `explicit`:

```
Foo f = Foo({{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}); // Compiles with clang and gcc.
// Foo g = Foo({{"a", "b"}});
Foo f2 = Foo({f});                     // No errors! Equivalent to Foo{f}
```

Since `Foo({f})` is equivalent to `Foo{f}`, then g could be considered the same as:

```
Foo g = Foo{{"a", "b"}};
```

The compiler won't do the same for f because there is no foo constructor that takes two arguments (i.e., `{"a","b"}` and `{"c","d"}`).

In addition, consider what happens when you explicitly construct a `std::string` from "a" and "b":

```
Foo g = Foo({{std::string("a"), std::string("b")}});
```

This runs just fine. That is because the compiler can clearly see that `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>` is a better choice than `Foo` because std::pair can be constructed from two `std::string`'s

**In conclusion:**
One of the two things is most likely true:

- GCC simply is confused about what we are trying to do, as it sees
  `Foo(const Foo&)` and `Foo(const std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>&)` both take one
  argument and both *seem* to be equally valid.
- Since `Foo({...})` is equivalent to `Foo{...}`, the compiler is confused by the fact that we are calling `Foo{{"a","b"}}`, trying to create a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>` from "a" and "b".

**The solutions:**

- Use `Foo{{{"a", "b"}}}` instead; or:
- Put `using namspace std::string_literals` in your code and replace `Foo({{"a", "b"}})` with `Foo({{"a"s, "b"s}})`; or:
- Use `std::make_pair`

**EDIT:** One more important point: if you delete the Foo copy constructor, it becomes apparent that the compiler is trying to create a pair from "a" and another from "b". Take a look at the error message for this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(const std::vector< std::pair<std::string, std::string> >& list) {}
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo1({ {"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"} });
    Foo foo2({ {"a", "b"} });
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair,
> std::__cxx11::basic_string >::pair(const char&)’

**PLEASE NOTE:** this is just a combination of what I know about `std::initializer_list`'s and my inferences about what is happening. Take this answer with a grain of salt, what is *possibly* occurring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Captain Hatteras, and also @upkajdt.  I'll need to set aside time to carefully read your argument, but it sounds plausible. The ```Foo{{{"a", "b"}}}``` approach does indeed work with gcc.